# MultiDexApplication Class Not Found

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-multidex

I'm using MultiDex with Proguard, and it works fine for every phone with API >= 21, probably even 20 (Can't download it on emulator), but my min SDK is set to 19, and on 19 it throws this error

```
Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Why is that, and can I fix it?

Comment: So do you have: [Multidex support prior to Android 5.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-pre-l) in your gradle? And if so what other code shrinking have you done?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes, i have this support library added in my gradle. And I'm not sure what you mean by other code shrinking. I use default Proguard rules with few exceptions added, so it keeps some of my code untouched, like my Data Objects and i added some Firebase '-keep' rules too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, guys, i found the solution here. I tried many different things recommended everywhere, tried to extend Application class, install multiDex in `onCreate` , `attachBaseContext`, tried adding multiDex keep files, tried it on different devices and all that stuff, and the solution was just simple clean build.

I just went in Android Studio to `Build -> Clean Project` and now it runs on Android 19

Answer (score 0):

Inside your proguard config file, add below line:

```
-keep class android.support.multidex.** { *; }
```

This line is to keep class `MultiDexApplication` from being removed.

Comment: That's actually not a problem with Proguard, i have this line added, but if i disable Proguard i get the same error, I thought it was related to Proguard because of other "missing" errors, but they disappeared after I updated all the dependencies, now i have everything up to date and the MultiDex error still appears, maybe there was some update to one of my dependencies that causes this error. I'll edit the title so it won't be misleading